# Android should you really use by Lazy in ViewModel as per Docs?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

[This Android doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement) shows following code:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<User>>().also {
        loadUsers()
    }
  }

  fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
    return users
  }

  private fun loadUsers() {
    // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
  }
}
```

and I'm wondering if it is really correct to use **by lazy** or really needed since I can not encounter any projects using this. If you do use it and you for example do following:

```
private fun loadUsers() {
    // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
    users.value = ...
}
```

the code access "users" again and since it is not initialized yet loadUsers() is called again! Considering you observe **users** in an activity or fragment for example.

Comment: It’s weird to have a getter function in Kotlin instead of using a property, but that is probably an oversight they made when converting the original Java example. They are using lazy as a way of deferring the fetching of data until the moment when the data first has an observer attached, which might be desired behavior if there is something you don’t want to waste resources fetching until the user clicks something that will show that data. I find it more common to set all my observers up immediately because my screens don’t have hidden panels, so I’ve never had a need to do this.

Comment: If your ViewModel is shared by multiple screens, I think this pattern would be more useful because then the data could be fetched only once the user clicks through to a Fragment that shows that data.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks, those ideas are helpful to understand it. Maybe it also helps for decoupling since using by lazy the viewModel doesn't need to know if your view needs the data inmediately or uses a button or shares the ViewModel, etc.